# How to left align to a centered text in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-textview-autosize

The code below is producing this.

[image]

I would like this layout instead:

[image: Should be like this]

The large textView on top takes the full with of the parent and the textsize is auto-adjusting with android:autoSizeTextType="uniform".
I want to align the textViews below with the actual text, not with the frame of the textView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/black"
tools:context=".DisplayActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timeTextView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="5000dp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="2:01:04"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timeTextView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="148dp"
    android:text="2:01:05"

    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/timeTextView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timeTextView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="152dp"
    android:text="2:01:07"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/timeTextView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.59" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the size and relative position of the text in the top *TextView* will change depending upon screen size, orientation and autoresizing, there is not a single set of values that you can use to position the other two views and no constraint that will work, so you will have to approach this via code using the [Layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout) of the top *TextView* after the layout passes complete. The *Layout* will give you the values of where the text starts within the *TextView* and where it ends. See the comments in the following for details. I changed the layout a little for the demo. (There are two layouts here: One if the *ConstraintLayout* and the other is internal to the *TextView* which defines how the text appears.)

[image]

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView tv;
    private Guideline guidelineStart;
    private Guideline guidelineEnd;
    private ConstraintLayout layout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        // This is the top TextView
        tv = findViewById(R.id.timeTextView);
        
        // Get the vertical start and end guidelines which are set to 0% and 100% to start. The
        // left bottom TextView is constrained to the guidelineStart and the right bottom
        // TextView is constrained to guidelineEnd.
        guidelineStart = findViewById(R.id.guidelineStart);
        guidelineEnd = findViewById(R.id.guidelineEnd);
        
        // This is our ConstraintLayout. We will wait for everthing to layout so we can get
        // good measurements.
        layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
        layout.post(() -> {
            int layoutWidth = layout.getWidth();
            
            // Get the starting and ending positions from the Layout of the top TextView.
            float start = tv.getLayout().getLineLeft(0);
            float end = tv.getLayout().getLineRight(0);
            
            // Now set the start and end guidelines to shift our bottom two TextViews.
            // We could also use guidelines with pixel offsets.
            guidelineStart.setGuidelinePercent(start / layoutWidth);
            guidelineEnd.setGuidelinePercent(end / layoutWidth);
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="5000dp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="2:01:04"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.15" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeTextView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="2:01:05"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guidelineStart"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/timeTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeTextView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="2:01:07"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineEnd"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/timeTextView" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.0" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineEnd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you. It almost works. timeTextView in your code has a fixed height. That means the textSize is not really adjusting anymore to the screen size...

Comment: @Ketobomb That was a simplification for the demo. I updated the layout. Try it now.

Comment: It turns out this task is not trivial at all. While it looks fine on a phone, the alignment is off on the tablet 2560 x 1440. https://pasteboard.co/Kc9Qxgg.png

Comment: @Ketobomb Interesting. Works for me on a tablet emulators and an actual tablet. Which tablet/emulator are you seeing failure on? Which API if API-related. I loaded my [demo project](https://github.com/Cheticamp/TextPosition) on GitHub. I would be interested to know if it fails in the same way. I made a small change to accommodate text views that are not match_parent in width.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="5000dp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="2:01:04"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guideline6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeTextView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:text="2:01:05"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/timeTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeTextView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="2:01:07"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/timeTextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/timeTextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2" />
   
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.59" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

here is how it will look
[image]

Hope it work for you... :)

Comment: Thank you. It almost works. With a screen dimention of 1080x2220 the big text on the top is smaller than the 2 texts below.

Comment: @Ketobomb for that you need to try and test different text size.